# How do I get vim to show trailing whitespace, but use blank spaces for tabs?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want trailing whitespace to show as `.`, and tabs to show as blank spaces instead of `^I`.  I thought the solution would be easy:

```
set listchars=tab:  ,trail:.
set list
```

but that doesn't quite work:

```
Error detected while processing .vimrc:
line 11:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:
```

I suppose I have to escape or encode the whitespace somehow, but how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:.
```

Comment: Just so this is clear to anyone else: whatever the character you need to escape is, put a backslash before it, and a backslash and a space after it, before the comma.